# Replacing MS Access forms

Tags: ms-access, data-entry

We have a number of very old data entry forms that were made in Access that link to our SQL Server database. Each form may have any number of sub-forms.

We'd like to move away from using these access frontends but don't have the time to create a new app or web app to replace every form that we've got.

Is there another option that would link to SQL Server and allow visual design of the form and automatic linkage to the database?

Or if that's too much of an ask, can you think of a way to make hand-coding the forms easier?

Comment: What, exactly, is wrong with the Access forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From experience, I don't think you will find any product, tool or technology any easier than Access for creating forms with a DB behind them.

Do you have a copy of [Access Developer's Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0782140114)?   In the past, I found this a valuable resource for implementing best practices in quite complex projects with Access as a front-end to SQL Server.

If you want to move to web forms, I would take a look at [IronSpeed Designer](http://www.ironspeed.com/)

Comment: Ironspeed looks interesting - will give it a go. 

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I concur with other commenters.

The WORST thing about Access front-ends are deployment issues (although lightly used Access apps can run ok off a network file share which eases things a bit.)

But if development speed is a goal Access is still a great tool.  So for in-house applications Access can work.

Just my 2 ¢.

Seth